# Hangouts Button Web Integration

Tags: google-hangouts

I've found a problem. Hangouts button doesn't work properly.

I was following the instructions from https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button.

To check, I try to put in Chrome ?gid=">https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/?gid= **+** Mi **APP_ID**, that I understand is my "Project Number".

However, when I do this, the Web browser opens Hangouts but it stops waiting for a Email, and I think it should continue and establish the videocall directly with me, without asking anything.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know why, before the link for test, it has included at publish ?gid=">